# Stacked Bar Chart in R using ggplot2 (not possible in excel)

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have a pretty time sensitive questions and I hope you guys can help me figure it out.

So I have a huge data set that mimics the dataset below:

[Dataset Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyoiH.jpg)

I would like to create a stacked bar chart where the first block of the column is made by the 1st production of company A, the second block is made by the 1st production of company B and so on and the last block on the top is made up by that 100 unit production by B. So basically, the y axis is the hour, and x axis is the production, and each block is color-coded by the company.

I am trying to do this in R because it doesnt seem possible in excel.

Comment: Amd what exactly is your question?

Comment: How do I do it in R? 
I know it seems like I am not putting in any work. But I have been trying and am running into loads of issues. This is my first time using R so I am trying to get some help.

Comment: If you can provide a reproducible example of your data, or subset of your data, this shouldn't be too hard to help you with. Without being able to work with your data in R it's hard to know what will work for sure.

Comment: Hey guys, I have provided a subset of the data that I am using. I thought it wouldn't be too hard because technically, I can create coordinates for each cell and then plot it. But it has proven to be a lot harder. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Hey guys, I am able to solve it now for one hour. But it is because for one hour, I have two columns. How do I do it for multiple hours? I.e. can i program such that the company-variable are on the odd-numbered columns and the production-variable are the even-numbered columns

Comment: So I have another problem: I used the formula suggested below and it works if I only do it for one hour. But when I try to do it for multiple hours, this occur: 
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (2226): x, y, fill

This is my formula
ggplot(data=dataset, aes(x=hour, y=production, fill=company))+geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.5)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I reckon this might work but can't be sure without an example of your data

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = Company, y = Hour, fill = Production)) + 
    geom_bar()
```

Comment: Hi, I am gonna try to use this. But I have also updated my post to include my excel data image if that helps.

Comment: I have updated my problem. Do you think you could help me out. The updates are in the comments.